# How to convert big Sparse Matrix to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have a big sparse matrix (with 2140 columns and 1183747 rows) and I want to convert it to a data frame in R **(R version 3.3.1)**. I used the following code

```
dt <- fread("train.csv",
               colClasses = "character",
               na.strings = "")

data <- Matrix(as.matrix(dt), sparse = T)
train <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(data))
```

bu I got the following error:

```
cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Consider adding a reproducible example to your question so that people can help you more quickly.

Comment: It's a common problem, converting any big sparse matrix to a data frame, so you can create a sample sparse matrix with the mentioned size and try to convert it to a data frame, am I right?

Comment: @user2100721, how should I use {data.table}?

Comment: Converting to a matrix then a data frame worked for me. You will need to post some more details (e.g. code to create a matrix similar to the one you have, and perhaps the version of R you are using)

Comment: What do you see when you do `class(as.matrix(data))`?

Comment: @KeithHughitt : I see: Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Comment: You can directly read in the file as `t <- data.frame(fread("train.csv",
               colClasses = "character",
               na.strings = ""))` . See if that works .

Comment: @PankajKaundal : `fread` can directly read data as `data.frame`. Use `data.table` argument as `FALSE`.

Comment: Are you certain you have enough memory for the conversion? For instance, what happens if you make a random zero or binary matrix of the same size?

Comment: @KeithHughitt yes I do have enough memory! I always monitor the memory usage and it never reaches to the maximum which is 256GB! yes, it is a powerful computer ;)

Comment: What happens if you try and generate a sparse matrix with fake data using something like: `x <- rnorm(100);  x[!rbinom(100, 2, prob=0.01)] <- 0; z <- Matrix(x, ncol=10, sparse=TRUE)`  (but with dimensions and sparsity more similar to your actual data). Does converting it back to a matrix still fail? If so, how about if you decrease the dimensions significantly?

Comment: -1 it is not clear at all what are you trying to do. 1) read into df 2)then convert_dense->convert_sparse->convert_dense-> convert data.frame back. what are you doing?

Comment: @KeithHughitt, Thanks! converting it to matrix and then converting to data.frame worked! :)